# Integrating Gradio/Streamlit with Flask for Multi-Model Hosting and Route Customization

Tags: python, flask, routes, streamlit, gradio

**Issue:**

I'm in the process of deploying a sophisticated web application with a focus on machine learning model hosting using Gradio/Streamlit. While both frameworks offer exceptional ease-of-use, they inherently operate on singular ports and predominantly support the deployment of individual models per instance.

**Key Challenges:**

1. **Single Port Constraint:** Both Gradio and Streamlit, when initiated, bind themselves to a designated port.
2. **Limited Multi-Model Support:** The native setup doesn't facilitate simultaneous multi-model hosting on a unified dashboard.
3. **Route Rigidity:** I'm keen on mapping models to distinct endpoints while also interspersing custom UI components on alternative routes.
4. **iframe:** Would not prefer iframe as a solution

Considering Flask's robustness and flexibility, especially concerning route management, I'm exploring the feasibility of melding its capabilities with the aforementioned platforms.

**Desired Outcome:**
A seamlessly integrated environment where multiple models can co-exist, each accessible via a dedicated route, complemented by auxiliary UI elements distributed across other specific routes.

**Current Roadblock:**
Gradio/Streamlit's inherent architecture seemingly resists such extensive integration with Flask.

**Environment:**

- **Software/Platform:** Gradio, Streamlit, Flask.
- **Deployment Target:** (If applicable, e.g., local development, Docker, cloud service, etc.)

**Exploratory Measures:**

1. Delved into official and community-driven Gradio and Streamlit documentation.
2. Conducted preliminary experiments leveraging Flask's route functionalities.

**Question:**
Are there proven strategies or third-party extensions that allow for the seamless integration of Gradio/Streamlit with Flask, especially in the context of multi-model hosting and advanced route manipulation?
Or is there something else which I can use to achieve the above objective?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting idea to integrate several low-code web frameworks together.

Aside from the aforementioned `iframe` approach, flask's `render_template` may be a possible route but given that Streamlit apps is not static and is interactive in nature where the app reruns when interactive widgets are altered, this may not be feasible. Aside from this, Streamlit is an inherent web framework on itself that is based on the Tornado web framework and may have other rabbit holes to explore further ([see this related Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114207/can-a-streamlit-app-be-run-within-a-flask-app) for more info).

Sam Minot has written a great article in Towards Data Science ([Python-Based Data Viz (With No Installation Required](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-based-data-viz-with-no-installation-required-aaf2358c881)) showing a use case of embedding a Streamlit app in an HTML file using [`stlite`](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite) that is based on Web Assembly (a project that allows Python code to run inside a web browser) and powered by Pyodide.

Here's an example of Sam's embedding of a Streamlit app in an HTML file hosted on GitHub:
[image: Image from Sam Minot's blog]

Additionally, here's the [code snippet](https://github.com/FredHutch/stlite-template/blob/main/index.html) of the above mentioned HTML file in Sam's blog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <title>stlite app</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@stlite/mountable@0.7.1/build/stlite.css"
    />
    <style>
      footer {        
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      footer:after {
        content:'Based on github.com/FredHutch/stlite-template'; 
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px;
        top: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@stlite/mountable@0.7.1/build/stlite.js"></script>
    <script>
        fetch("app.py")
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then(
                (app) => stlite.mount(
                    {
                        requirements: ["click", "scipy", "plotly"],
                        entrypoint: "app.py",
                        files: {
                            "app.py": app
                        }
                    },
                    document.getElementById("root")
                )
            );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another route to explore could be [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/) (similar in concept with the above mentioned `stlite`) which allows Python to run in an HTML file.

Further ideas and information in venturing into this path could also be found in prior discussions in the Streamlit forum:

- https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/serve-streamlit-within-flask/493
- https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/integration-with-flask-app/809

Hope this helps!